# AngularJS filter JSON data by month dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am wondering if there is a way to filter JSON data by using a dropdown containing a list of all 12 months and filtering the listed results by month. I already have a filter in place that filters the data which in my case is a large list of events... by their corresponding type. But have not been able to figure out a way to filter the data by months using a dropdown.

The data goes as follows:

```
$scope.events = [{
      "id": "4330",
      "title": "Sweet Diezel Jenkins",
      "subtitle": null,
      "date": "2018-05-25 21:00:00",
},
{
      "id": "6401",
      "title": "Patricia Avis",
      "subtitle": null,
      "date": "2018-06-29 21:00:00"
}]
```

I grabbed two objects here as an example of how the data is setup. As you can see there is an event listed for May and an event listed for June.

I have attempted creating a filter function, also played around with loops to get it to work but nothing seemed to work. I noticed in the examples that I saw that the best way to do it is to create a custom Angular filter but since I'm fairly new to AngularJS I am very lost when it comes to implementing this month dropdown filter.

I am very curious if there is a simple filter that can be created in AngularJS that can filter this data by a month dropdown.

Comment: Include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: I have read through both of those in my search of a solution, they are helpful. But I am still struggling with the overall implementation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `model` in select `tag` and then you can [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your events data based on the selected value.

You can use `ng-change` directive to run the filter function everytime a different value is selected in

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', function($scope){

var events = [{
      "id": "4330",
      "title": "Sweet Diezel Jenkins",
      "subtitle": null,
      "date": "2018-05-25 21:00:00",
},
{
      "id": "6401",
      "title": "Patricia Avis",
      "subtitle": null,
      "date": "2018-06-29 21:00:00"
}];

$scope.events = events;
$scope.months = [{number : 1, month: 'Jan'},{number : 2, month: 'Feb'},{number : 3, month: 'Mar'},{number : 4, month: 'April'},{number : 5, month: 'May'},{number : 6, month: 'June'},{number : 7, month: 'Jul'},{number : 8, month: 'Aug'},{number : 9, month: 'Sep'},{number : 10, month: 'Oct'},{number : 11, month: 'Nov'},{number : 12, month: 'Dec'}];
//$scope.sel= 1;

$scope.filter = function(){

$scope.events = events.filter(o=> new Date(o.date).getMonth() +1 == $scope.sel)

}

//$scope.filter();
})
```

```css
select{
 margin-bottom : 30px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

   <select ng-model="sel" ng-change="filter()">
      <option ng-repeat="month in months" value="{{month.number}}">{{month.month}}     </option>
   </select>

    
  {{events}}
</div>
```

Comment: Can the dates be formatted as the full month name instead of a number? Great example by the way!

Comment: yes. you see the `months` array. Just add objects there with key as number and value as month name. lemme update

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you so much!

Comment: I would like to add... how would I list all of the events prior to nothing being selected? Let's say the first option on the dropdown is "select something". Is there a way to list all of the events when no months are selected?

Comment: You see this line in code `$scope.sel= 1;` ? this is actually setting the value of selected when you run the script.  You can deal with it as you want

Comment: I understand that but is there a way to list every event for all corresponding months? and then filter them when an option is selected instead of just showing a blank page until one of the months is clicked?

Comment: just remove `$scope.filter();` coz this is the function that runs on page load and adds filter to events.

Comment: I completely missed that at the bottom... yikes. Thanks again!